# Blank Location Field for Meeting Workspace

Tags: outlook, meeting-workspace

We have a client with Sharepoint 2010 Standard and Outlook 2010 on their build who want to create meeting workspaces in Sharepoint from Outlook.

We can create Meeting Workspaces within SP - all the templates are there. However when we try to create it in Outlook, the 'Location' field is blank and does not have the 'Other' option to specify the path:

[image]

Any idea how to get these options to show? I've been combing the net for ages but can only find answers for how to add the button to the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Have managed to resolve this myself, for reference if anyone else has the problem, you need to add the following registry entry:

Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Meetings\Profile\MRUInternal (REG_SZ)

With the following values:

https://contoso.forums.co.za/|Meetings Workspace|1033|{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}#1ContosoExcoForumTemplate|Contoso Exco Forum Template||

• Field 1: Server URL
• Field 2: Server friendly name
• Field 3: TemplateLCID
• Field 4: TemplateID
• Field 5: TemplateName
• Field 6: OrganizerName

Details of the values to use at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179098(v=office.12).aspx